# Condition on text vs math symbol

Tags: math-mode

I'd like to have a conditional macro that emboldens symbols, using different commands depending on whether the argument is a math symbol or text.     Specifically, I'd like to use \bm for math symbols and \mathbf for alphanumeric characters.   Thus it would look something like

```
\def\vec#1{\ifthenelse{\ismathsymbol{#1}}{\bm{#1}}{\mathbf{#1}}
```

Problem is I don't know of a test such as \ismathsymbol.  Obviously, it would be just fine if there were a test for alphanumeric characters.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: `\newcommand\vec[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle And don't load `amssymb`?

Comment: Math symbol vs text? You mean `v`, `\nu`, `AB` are math symbols but `shift` is text? How can TeX Tell the difference between the last two?